# Object issue in VBA

Tags: vba

I am starting out with VBA and have encountered issues with the following code. Ultimately I just want to store the row for use later. Can someone assist me please?

```vb
Sub UpdateQuote()

Dim wb As Workbook
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim FoundCell As Range
Dim FoundRow As Range
Dim FindValue As String

Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
Set ws = ActiveSheet

FindValue = Sheet24.Range("D3")

Set FoundCell = Sheet20.Range("A:A").Find(What:=FindValue)
Set FoundRow = FoundCell.Row

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

MsgBox FoundRow

End Sub
```

Comment: `Dim FoundRow As Long: FoundRow = FoundCell.Row`

Comment: To explain a little more about what **Tim Williams** said, the `Range.Row` will return the index of the selected row as `Long` value, so you need to change `FoundRow` type to `Long`

Comment: [Row](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.row) property documentation. It's important to consult the documentation of whatever property/method/object you are using, especially when you are new.

Comment: Thank you for the responses and noted. I have updated Dim FoundRow as Long and am now getting an Compile Error: Object Required

Comment: Thank you. Error checking needed to be added and is now working